# Как запустить приложение от имени администратора через cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10, bat

Есть необходимость запускать командную строку (или любой другой файл) от имени администратора, причем получать тот же результат, что и при нажатии провой кнопкой и выборе "Запуск от имени администратора".

Нужно запустить процесс от имени администратора из обычной `cmd`, вызванной из меню "Выполнить" (`Win+R`).

---

**Пробовал запускать от имени пользователя с правами администратора:**

```
runas /user:denisnumb cmd.exe
```

Но при попытке копировать файл в системную папку пишет "Отказано в доступе". При этом, если я запущу `cmd.exe` от имени админа при помощи выбора пункта в контекстном меню, то получу полноценную `cmd` с правами администратора.

**Как запустить процесс с правами админа из `cmd` также, как и из контекстного меню?**

Comment: после `/user:` нужно указать имя админа, причём вместе с доменом (см.справку - runas/?)

Comment: Да, что-то такое подмечали на других форумах. Могу я узнать, что подразумевается под именем админа? Единственный пользователь, и админ по совместительству, это я - `denisnumb`. Что нужно указывать в качестве домена?

Comment: `Что нужно указывать в качестве домена?` - [Win+Break] --> Имя компьютера

Comment: Имя ПК - `denisnumb`. Таким образом, при вводе `runas /user:denisnumb\denisnumb cmd.exe` cmd запускается, но работать с файлами в системной папке я все еще не могу, да и права особо не отличаются от обычной cmd

Comment: Тогда не знаю.. вроде должно работать. Можно ещё проверить, точно-ли вы админ на данной машине командой в консоли: `net localgroup администраторы`

Comment: Да, админ. Ладно, проще все же вручную запускать через ПКМ > Запуск от имени администратора

Comment: Существует небезопасный способ: отключить уведомления UAC с целью запуска приложений в привилегированном режиме. Данный вопрос уже не раз обсуждался на смежных форумах. Есть другие способы: встраивание в batch-файл функций запроса на повышение привилегий (аналогично - в VBS-скриптах). Можно использовать аналоги su: elevate,winsudo. С использованием встроенных средств, лично я решал проблему, задействовав Планировщик задач, который по триггеру запускал нужное мне приложение в административных привилегиях (триггер я инициировал ручным запуском).